# $\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)\simeq S_4$

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)\simeq S_4$.

If $G$ is a finite group, $p$ divides $|G|$, $n=n_p(G):=|\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)|$ then we know that $\operatorname{Aut} G\le S_n$. I used this to prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)\le S_4$, since $n_3(A_4)=4$.

But now, how can I show the inverse inclusion, i.e. that $S_4\le \operatorname{Aut}(A_4)$?

I know that $S_4\simeq \operatorname{Aut}(S_4)$ but I don't know if it could help.

Any hint would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $S_4$ acts on $A_4$ by conjugation.

Comment: The claim in the first sentence of the second paragraph is false (e.g. we might have $n_p = 1$); maybe it's true with more conditions but they haven't been stated. See the comments of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808610/if-g-is-a-finite-group-p-is-a-prime-such-that-p-bigg-and-n-p-is-the

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every element of $S_4$ gives you an automorphism of $A_4$ by conjugation, since $A_4$ is normal in $S_4$. The elements of $S_4$ which act trivially by conjugation on $A_4$ are precisely the elements of the centralizer $C_{S_4}(A_4)$, which is trivial, hence every element of $S_4$ gives you a distinct automorphism of $A_4$.

Comment: Thank you! But, how can I show that $C_{S_4}(A_4)$ is trivial?

Comment: Any element of $A_4$ can be written as $(ab)(cd)$ or $(abc)$. In either case, $(ac)$ does not commute with it.

Comment: Many many thanks!

Comment: If you're not convinced every element of $A_4$ can be written that way, simply note that $A_4$ has 12 elements. There are (4 choose 3) = 4 ways to pick 3 elements to go in a 3-cycle, and for each choice of 3 elements, two ways to arrange them, ie $(abc)$ or $(acb)$. Hence there are 8 distinct 3-cycles, all in $A_4$. What about stuff like $(ab)(cd)$? Well there are (4 choose 2) = 6 ways to pick $a,b$, but picking $a,b$ is the same as picking $c,d$, so there are 3 distinct permutations of the form $(ab)(cd)$. So far we've accounted for 11. The 12th is just the identity.

Comment: Sorry: in order to explain this, isn't easier to notice that $A_4$ is the group of even $2$-cycles on $4$ elements? Hence every element of $A_4$ can be written as $(ab)(cd)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Joe You're right, but my explanation allowed us to consider $a,b,c,d$ all to be distinct numbers, upon which my argument relied. If you want to say that every element of $A_4$ can be written as $(ab)(cd)$, then some of the $a,b,c,d$ may be the same, and strictly speaking, you should consider arbitrary products of 2-cycles, ie $(ab)(cd)(ef)$ or $(ab)(cd)(ef)(gh)$,...etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=A_4$,

By the fact you mentioned, $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\leq S_4 $ and since $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)\cong G\leq\operatorname{Aut}(G)$;
we have $$A_4\leq\operatorname{Aut}(G)\leq S_4$$.

Since $A_4$ is only subgroup of $S_4$ with order $12$ it is characteristic in $S_4$ which means there is a homomorphism from $
\operatorname{Aut}(S_4)\cong S_4$ to $
\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and since $
\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has at least $12$ elements and $S_4$ has no normal subgroup of order $2$, we have isomorphism from $S_4$ to $
\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.