# How to compute quickly the order of the automorphism group of $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

I'm recently got interested by a series of very cool videos by Math Doctor Bob, specifically the ones about to compute automorphism groups. The one puzzling me a bit is this one: [Automorphism of A4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqpBmtfVwVg&list=PLF379B0552AD17780&t=0s&index=21)

Without forcing any of you to to watch the video, I'm just resuming here what I have not understood. Basically, he's able to estimate the order of the automorphism group of $A_4$ to 24 elements, establishing finally this must be isomorphic to $S_4$. Actually these are the facts:

1) $A_4$ is made up by the identity, 3 cycles of order 2 (like (1 2)(3 4)) and 8 cycles of order 3.

2) $A_4 = <( 1 2 3), (1 2)(3 4)>$, i.e. can be generated by a cycle of order 3 and one of order 2.

So fa, so good. Here he claims 2 interesting facts, which are the core business of this question indeed:

> 1) if we have automorphism, we have to preserve the order of elements. So a 3 cycles has to be carried to another 3-cycles and a couple to a couple (I condensed it a bit)

Assuming the above point, the results turns out naturally as a combinatorial reasoning, i.e.

> you have 8 choices for a 3-cycle and 3 choices for a (2,2)-cycle, so a total of 24 choices

This made up the order of $Aut(A_4)$. With later reasoning is desuming this must be $S_4$, indeed.

What I'm struggling with is why an automorphism of a alternating group must preserve the order. I mean, these facts are clear to me:

1) $Inn(A_4) \lhd Aut(A_4)$
2) $Inn(A_4)$ acts by conjugation and then must preserve cycle order (even this is the case in which the conjugacy classes split, however the order is guaranteed)

What I'm missing here (my bad) is it seems we are assuming $Aut(A_4)$ is made up only by $Inn(A_4)$, but this not since the $Out(A_4)$ is not trivial but being isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2$. Since this latter involves an odd permutation, the order would be not guaranteed in that case.

I'm sure I'm wrong, but I don't know where.

thank for your precious support, as always.

Comment: Compare with a standard solution from [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815166/operatornameauta-4-simeq-s-4). Every automorphism preserves all invariants of a group, because it is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$. Start with $a^n=e$. Then $(f(a))^n=f(a^n)=f(e)=e$. Now use $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Also, you say "it seems that we are assuming ${\rm Aut}(A_4)$ is made up only by ${\rm Inn}(A_4)$", but we are not assuming that and,as you say, it is not true.

Comment: @Derek, yes I realised immediately this was not true. Infact it's exactly that wrong assumption which makes me crazy.

Comment: @Dietrich, thank for pointing out to that link, since I missed that out. I see your point, it makes more sense now. However, I have to say I have a big amount or groups related books, but none of them are really describing well how to compute neatly an automorphism group from group.It's a very and interesting by itself. I mean, if the group is a symmetric or an alternating one, could make sense using orders. But for more complex groups I guess it could be not so easy. Thanks

Comment: @Derek, I finally realised where my assumption was wrong. Actually, as the link gently suggested is listing, $S_4$ acts on $A_4$ by conjugation, and by this you can proof it made up the whole $Aut(A_4)$, indeed. The true source of my confusion raised to confuse that with $Inn(A_4)$, but conjugating by $S_4$ is a completely a different story than conjugating INSIDE $A_4$ only. This is also supported by the fact, as we agreed above, that $Inn(A_4)$ is a subgroup of $Aut(A_4)$, which is the full $S_4$, indeed. Thanks.