# Can we define a natural isomorphism $\phi: S_4 \to {\rm Aut}(A_4)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I was recently viewing [$\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)\simeq S_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815166/operatornameauta-4-simeq-s-4). Why is ${\rm Aut}(A_4)$ isomorphic to $S_4$ has been asked quite a bit on this site -- and I understand the logic in the linked answer.

However, what I'm wondering is, can we actually write down a natural, explicit (injective and surjective) homomorphism between these two groups ? It's a bit hard for me to imagine this -- since the automorphism group is a group of maps, while $S_4$ consists of permutations. How can we send elements in the automorphism group to $S_4$ in a natural way ?

Thanks for your help. (=

Comment: I hope the following comment is taken in the friendly tone I am intending: I think you should reconsider whether you understand the linked answer, because it actually does explain how to make the bijection explicit. As I'm sure you know, $A_{4}$ is the subgroup of $S_{4}$ consisting of even permutations. $A_{4}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{4}$ (why?), so it is stable under conjugation by any element of $S_{4}$. The desired bijection $\varphi \colon S_{4} \to Aut(A_{4})$ sends an element $\sigma \in S_{4}$ to the map $A_{4} \to A_{4}$ given by $\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: No offense taken, sir. Thanks for your reply. I will try to understand the linked answer better! (=

Comment: There are a few details which are worth explaining here, namely: (1) why is $\varphi$ a group homomorphism? (2) for any fixed $\sigma \in S_{4}$, why is the map $\varphi(\sigma) \colon A_{4} \to A_{4}$ a group homomorphism on $A_{4}$? why is it bijective?  (3) lastly, why is $\varphi$ a bijection? This third crucial point is what the linked answer explains. As a last stray comment, the word ''natural'' has a specific meaning in algebra which is different from its usual English usage. You might want to keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: It's certainly, in some sense(s), natural to consider the inner automorphisms.  The conjugation action is well known to be transitive.  So you do get a map to the automorphism group.  That all this ends up working out, is quite fortuitous.  Several things go right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just given the bare fact that $\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)\cong S_4$, without considering whatever proof was given, here is a way to construct such an isomorphism:

First note that $\operatorname{Aut}(S_n)\cong S_n$ for almost all $n$, the only exceptions being $n=2$ and $n=6$. For each $n$ we have a natural map
$$S_n\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(S_n):\ \sigma\ \longmapsto\ (\tau\ \mapsto\ \sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}),$$
which sends each $\sigma\in S_n$ to the automorphism of $S_n$ given by conjugation by $\sigma$. Note that this map in fact defines a group homomorphism $G\ \rightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ for *any* group $G$.

Because $A_4\subset S_4$ is the unique subgroup of $S_4$ of order $12$, it is mapped to itself by every automorphism of $S_4$. This means the map above induces a group homomorphism
$$S_4\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(A_4):\ \sigma\ \longmapsto\ (\tau\ \mapsto\ \sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}).$$
Since you already know that $\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)\cong S_4$, to prove that it is an ismorphism, it suffices to prove it is injective, or equivalently, that only the identity element $e\in S_4$ acts trivially on $A_4$ by conjugation. Put more simply; that the only element $\sigma\in S_4$ for which $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}=\tau$ holds for *all* $\tau\in A_4$, is the identity $e\in S_4$.